# Same click event for multiple elements, specific case

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't want to repeat my code so I am trying to figure out how to work with a click event on multiple elements:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var realStateBtn = $('#real-estate-center').parent();
    var link = $('#real-estate-center > .linkwidth');
    realStateBtn.css('zIndex', 9999);
    realStateBtn.click(function() {
        console.log('TRIGGERED');
        window.location.href='http://realestatecenter.bankofamerica.com/';
    });

    link.click(function() {
        window.location.href="http://realestatecenter.bankofamerica.com/";
    });
});
```

as you see the vars `realStateBtn` and `link` take you to the same place/has the same function applied so what can I do in order to put the same code into one function?

I know I can do something like this:

`$('.class1, class2').click(...)`

but in this case I have this elements:

`$('#real-estate-center').parent();`

`$('#real-estate-center > .linkwidth');`

Suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`.add()`](https://api.jquery.com/add/) method to combine jQuery objects.

```
realStatebtn.add(link).click(function() {
    console.log('TRIGGERED');
    window.location.href='http://realestatecenter.bankofamerica.com/';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's exactly as you said: move the code into a single function:

```
function move() {
   window.location.href='http://realestatecenter.bankofamerica.com/';
}

realStateBtn.click(move);
link.click(move);
```

Here is a jsfiddle showing the concept: https://jsfiddle.net/b0ynfnmn/

Answer (score 0):

You could add a common class and listen the click event on this class:

```
// Store the elements you want to an array
var elems = [];
elem.push(realStateBtn);
elem.push(link);
// You can add more elements ...
```

Now iterate the array and add the same class:

```
for(var elem in elems) {
   elems[elem].addClass('my-element');
}
```

Add the appropriate event listener (using event delegation in order to work):

```
// Add event listener using event delegation
$(document).on('click', '.my-element', function() {
   window.location.href="http://realestatecenter.bankofamerica.com/";
});
```